# ¿Cómo insertar valores de variables en array?

Tags: php

tengo 4 variables, cada una con su valor y necesito meter en un array los valores de esas variables. Estoy probando con un `for` pero no llego a conseguir el resultado que deseo.

Este es mi código:

```
$variable1 = "hola";
$variable2 = "mundo";
$variable3 = "prueba";
$variable4 = "esto";

$arrayValores = array();

$nombre = "variable";

for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    array_push($arrayValores, $nombre.$i);
}


print_r($arrayValores);
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
Array ( [0] => variable1 [1] => variable2 [2] => variable3 [3] => variable4 )
```

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Por cierto, debes inicializar el array $arrayValores para evitar warnings de php o usa el método sencillo de añadir elementos $arrayValores[]=...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Espero sea lo que buscas.

```
<?php
    $variable1 = "hola";
    $variable2 = "mundo";
    $variable3 = "prueba";
    $variable4 = "esto";

    $arrayValores = array();

    $nombre = "variable";

    for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
        array_push($arrayValores, ${$nombre.$i });
    }
    print_r($arrayValores);
?>
```

```
Salida: Array ( [0] => hola [1] => mundo [2] => prueba [3] => esto )
```

Te recomiendo y leas un poco la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) para comprendas mucho mejor

Comment: Perfecto! Esto era lo que estaba buscando!

Answer (score 3):

Concatena el valor numérico y después usa la variable:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $nombre = 'variable'.$i;
    array_push($arrayValores, $$nombre);
}
```

Usa comillas simples siempre que puedas, las comillas dobles hacen que php busque variables dentro de ellas, por ejemplo:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $nombre = "variable$i";
    array_push($arrayValores, $$nombre);
}
```

Comment: Pero con cualquiera de los dos bucles, en el array se está metiendo el nombre de la variable pero no el valor

Comment: si, perdón , lo corrijo ahora mismo, falta un $. Gracias.

Comment: Ahora sí! Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Si bien ya tienes excelentes respuestas, me gustaría proponer:

```
$arrayVariables = [
        $variable1 = "hola",
        $variable2 = "mundo",
        $variable3 = "prueba",
        $variable4 = "esto",
    ];
    
$arrayNuevo = [];

for($contador = 0; $contador < count($arrayVariables); $contador++) {
    array_push($arrayNuevo, $arrayVariables[$contador]);
}

print_r($arrayNuevo);
```

Cuya salida sería esta:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hola
    [1] => mundo
    [2] => prueba
    [3] => esto
)
```

Como notas:

- Las variables quedan dentro de un array
- El ciclo for iterará mientras el contador sea menor al conteo de elementos de dicho array
- Cuando vamos agregando los elementos al array vacío, empleamos la sintaxis de: **`$arrayOriginal[$variableContador]`**
- Por fuera del loop obtenemos el array con los valores de las variables acumulados en el

Comment: Me fijaría más por esta respuesta. +1

Comment: Se supone que las variables se van inicializando a lo largo del código, si se crea la estructura adhoc ya compesaría hacerlo directamente solo con los valores $arrayValores = ["hola","mundo","prueba","esto"];  y evitamos el for.

Comment: Cierto es @Fly por eso lo dejé solo como *una mera opción*